# how to implement particular message format in NS-2

Tags: simulation, wireless, simulator, public-key-encryption, ns2

i need a little help regarding NS-2
My question is can you implement a particular message format between two nodes in NS-2 like we create a tcp communication but if i want to send particular message eg
a certificate with information inside it such as public key or type of node time, etc.
i am trying to do it in wireless
and also can it be encrypted.
is there any example or sample code or snippet you can share

Answer (score 0):

Creation of your own packets in aodv is so easy. Have a look at it.
http://karthicksivakrr.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-can-i-create-my-own-packets-in-aodv.html